# Как переносить цифры из входной строки в выходную?

Tags: python, строки, словари, реализация

Моя попытка реализации (не знаю, как переносить цифры из входной строки в выходную):

```
s1 = list(input())
s2 = list(input())
sd = list(input())
snew = ""
for i in range(len(s1)):
   dictionary = {s1[el] : s2[el]        for el in range(len(s1))}
   dictionary_up = {s1[el].upper() : s2[el].upper() for el in range(len(s1))}
for i in range(len(sd)):
    if sd[i].isupper():
     snew+= dictionary_up[sd[i]]
    if not sd[i].isupper():
        snew+= dictionary[sd[i]]
print(snew)
```

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYwcw.jpg![введите](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYwcw.jpg!%5B%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5) сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqfs4.jpg)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, перенабирать ваши примеры, которые вы соизволили приложить в виде картинки, вместо требуемых правилом сайте ВОСПРОИЗВОДИМЫХ данных, я не намерен, поэтому вот вам решение, а уж под свой ввод и вывод подстраивайте самостоятельно.

```
in_kb='qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm'
ot_kb='mnbvcxzlkjhgfdsapoiuytrewq'
input_st='erTy,u 2iIj'
#######
out_lt=''
for lt in input_st:
    if lt.lower() in in_kb :
        if lt.islower():
            out_lt+=ot_kb[in_kb.index(lt)]
        else:
            out_lt+=ot_kb[in_kb.index(lt.lower())].upper()
    else:
       out_lt+=lt
#########
print(out_lt)
```

Результат:

```
bvCx,z 2lLp
```

Answer (score 2):

как вариант, можете воспользоваться методом `translate` (входные данные позаимствованы у [passant](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1375458/457260)):

```
s1 = 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm'
s2 = 'mnbvcxzlkjhgfdsapoiuytrewq'
sd = 'erTy,u 2iIj'

new = sd.translate(str.maketrans(s1 + s1.upper(), s2 + s2.upper()))

print(new)  # bvCx,z 2lLp
```

Comment: Точно, совсем из головы выпало! Единственное что заставляет задуматься -  что там с производительностью (если это важно), но признаю, красивое решение!

Comment: спасибо большое за верные решения)